# Full width section image not zooming

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, modern-pages, image-display

I created Full width section in SharePoint Online page and added Image web part to it. My image is quite narrow with size 2560x394. All seems fine on computer screen, however on mobile screen this image is not zooming in, but instead resizing to become really small image (not possible to see anything):

```
PC screen:
```

[image]

```
Mobile screen:
```

[image]

I tried Hero web part, which is also available in Full-width section and image in there is zooming in, instead of resizing, however Hero webpart itself is too large and takes too much page space, so I cannot use it.

Is there any other options how to make Image webpart zoom in, instead of resizing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by design, Images in `full-width` columns will always display at the full width of your screen with an **automatic** height based on screen size.

So in your case, the issue is mainly related to the height of your image which is set automatically based on your Mobile screen.

> See also [Image sizing and scaling in SharePoint modern pages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/image-sizing-and-scaling-in-sharepoint-modern-pages-dc510065-b5a5-4654-bc94-e3ecbbb57d8d)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what are my options if I wanted to not adjust height based on screen size ? Is the only one to create my own SPFx Image webpart myselft or maybe you know of any others ?